# Reverse order in evaluated list

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, sorting

I solve the following set of ODE and plot solution of S1 vs k2 (Figure 1).

```
k1 = 1;
k3 = 5;
n = 3;
c = 1;
v0 = 15.0;
dk = -0.0005;
s = NDSolve[{
    S1'[t] == v0 - k2[t]*S1[t]*(1 + c*S2[t]^n) - k1*S1[t],
    S2'[t] == k2[t]*S1[t]*(1 + c*S2[t]^n) - k3*S2[t],
    k2'[t] == dk,
    S1[0] == 1,
    S2[0] == 1,
    k2[0] == 0.5}, {S1, S2, k2}, {t, 2100}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{k2[t], S1[t]} /. s], {t, 300, 450}, 
AspectRatio -> 0.5, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {k2, S1}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0.275, 0.0}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

I would like k2 to be displayed from high to low values (basically, to revere X-axis, like in Figure 2). I tried Reverse and Sort, but did not manage them to work with Evaluate.

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not clear whether or not you like to shift the x-axis too, to make it appear in almost the same place, but here is a start:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{0.625 - k2[t], S1[t]} /. s], {t, 300, 450}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {k2, S1}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0.275, 0.0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you like to have correct ticks that match your original function, then you need to manually adjust them too. Basically, you the same thing to your ticks that you did to the function: you negate it. I supply two lists of ticks, because I want to have smaller sub-ticks that don't have a label too.

```
ticks[min_, max_] := Join[
   Table[{i, NumberForm[-i, 2], {-0.01, 0}}, {i, min, max, 0.01}],
   Table[{i, , {-0.005, 0}}, {i, min, max, 0.0025}]];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{-k2[t], S1[t]} /. s], {t, 300, 450}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {k2, S1}, 
 Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.